# Blazor page's URL is interfering with component's call to API -- 400-Bad Request

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

My web-app is .Net 6, VS-2022 Blazor WASM-hosted.

I am having a problem with the URL for the API when being called from a component.
I have three files:  page: VehicleList.razor, page: VehicleEdit.Razor and component: CRUD_Vehicle.razor.

The page flow is the user navigates to 'VehicleList' and has the ability to select a vehicle to EDIT via callback function.  Once selected, the flow navigates to 'VehicleEdit' where some data needs to be passed to support the embedded sub-component 'CRUD_Vehicle'.

The problem is that URL to the 'VehicleEdit' looks like this with query-string data in a comma-delimited string AND it remains there when the CRUD-component is showing.

> https://localhost:7777/vehicleedit/667?par=17,Bigelow,Active

When the user makes editing changes and SUBMITs the component, the HttpClient service gets called and fails with a 400-Bad Request.  I am under the impression that the query-string interfers with the api URL.  Please see below. Is there a way I could set the URL to not show the query-string and only have the base-address and the UID_VEHICLE like this?

> https://localhost:7777/vehicleedit/667

```
public async Task<Vehicle> UpdateVehicle(Vehicle pVehicle) {
    // Save the edited record.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync<Vehicle>($"/api/vehicle/{pVehicle.UID_VEHICLE}", pVehicle);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        // problems handling here.
        Console.WriteLine($"UpdateVehicle() Error occurred, the status code is: {(int)response.StatusCode}: {response.StatusCode}" );
    }
    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Vehicle>();
}
```

I have a similar construction for the editing of the Customer object, but the page that shows the CRUD_Customer component has a simple URL and works perfectly to save data to the DB.  The main difference is the URL for the VehicleEdit.razor.  Your comments are welcome.
Thanks.

> https://localhost:7777/customeredit/17

Comment: The URL is a string and you can simply put the missing parameters (after the question mark) into the URL by adding to the URL string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you please show me what you mean?  Where does this change need to be coded?  Are you suggesting I need to have the same URL as the when the page is launched to pass to the httpClient-service JSON-call? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded Postman and entered the PUT transaction and the PUT RESULT showed there was an ERROR (based on DataAnnotation for the 'StartDate'-field) that was NOT caught at the client validation code.  It turns out that the TITLE text was based on what the possible cause might be.  But Postman showed me the exact reason why the PUT call failed.

So, my 'answer' is:  Use Postman to simulate the 'httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync'-call to observe the result-details to pinpoint the reason for the '400-Bad Request' return from the service.